# SQLAlchemy column with enum using PEP 435 compliant enum produces table creation error

Tags: python, orm, enums, sqlalchemy

I have an enum... defined very similarly to [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum).

When I try to create a table using the enum, as in the example, I get an error during table creation. It is a very vague error. Here is code that replicates the problem:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, Column, Enum, create_engine
import enum
class myEnum(enum.Enum):
    one = 'one'
    two = 'two'
    three = 'three'

def main():
    e = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
    e.echo = True
    m = MetaData(bind = e)
    t = Table('table', m, Column('my_enum', Enum(myEnum)))
    t.create()
if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

I get an `AttributeError: replace` when I run this code, with a seemingly useless stacktrace. I honestly don't even know where to begin debugging this and while I can conceive of a couple of possible workarounds, I am relatively new to SQLAlchemy so I'm not sure what the cleanest solution is. Surely basic enum support is a relatively simple expectation of a ORM framework?

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "table_test.py", line 17, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "table_test.py", line 16, in main
    t.create()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 725, in create
    checkfirst=checkfirst)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1856, in _run_visitor
    conn._run_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1481, in _run_visitor
    **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 121, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 764, in visit_table
    include_foreign_key_constraints=include_foreign_key_constraints
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 914, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 68, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_ddl(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 962, in _execute_ddl
    compiled = ddl.compile(dialect=dialect)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 494, in compile
    return self._compiler(dialect, bind=bind, **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\ddl.py", line 26, in _compiler
    return dialect.ddl_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 190, in __init__
    self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 213, in process
    return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 81, in _compiler_dispatch
    return meth(self, **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 2173, in visit_create_table
    create.include_foreign_key_constraints)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 2220, in create_table_constraints
    for constraint in constraints
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 2218, in <genexpr>
    p for p in
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 2226, in <genexpr>
    not getattr(constraint, 'use_alter', False)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 213, in process
    return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 93, in _compiler_dispatch
    return meth(self, **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 2369, in visit_check_constraint
    literal_binds=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 213, in process
    return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 81, in _compiler_dispatch
    return meth(self, **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 927, in visit_binary
    return self._generate_generic_binary(binary, opstring, **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 944, in _generate_generic_binary
    binary.right._compiler_dispatch(self, **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 81, in _compiler_dispatch
    return meth(self, **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 527, in visit_grouping
    return "(" + grouping.element._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs) + ")"
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 81, in _compiler_dispatch
    return meth(self, **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 751, in visit_clauselist
    for c in clauselist.clauses)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 748, in <genexpr>
    s for s in
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 751, in <genexpr>
    for c in clauselist.clauses)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 81, in _compiler_dispatch
    return meth(self, **kw)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 1071, in visit_bindparam
    bindparam, within_columns_clause=True, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 1103, in render_literal_bindparam
    return self.render_literal_value(value, bindparam.type)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 1118, in render_literal_value
    return processor(value)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\sqltypes.py", line 171, in process
    value = value.replace("'", "''")
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\enum.py", line 268, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name) from None
AttributeError: replace
```

Comment: What version of SQLAlchemy? Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Version 1.0.13... I will update the original post with the full stack trace momentarily.

Comment: [PEP-435 enum support](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/changelog_11.html#change-9d6d98d7acabc8564b8eebb11c28a624) is added in 1.1 (currently in beta).

Comment: @univerio:  You should make that an answer.  Maybe add the expected release date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PEP-435 enum support](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/changelog_11.html#change-9d6d98d7acabc8564b8eebb11c28a624) is being added in 1.1.

1.1.0b1 was recently released. You can upgrade to 1.1.0b1 but be wary of bugs. Based on release history I would say the stable version should be released in a month or two.

how to upgrade:

```
pip install 'sqlalchemy==1.1.0b3'
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. It is slightly annoying when developers upgrade the "latest" version of the docs to a version that isn't actually officially released.